# Playing an MP3 fle from a local computer in a HTML5 Website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio-player

I making a website just for fun and I want to be able to cycle through many different mp3's that are stored on my computer but eventually will be stored on my domain. I also want to be able to seek to a different point of the song. This is just a starting point for me but I would eventually like it so that a user can select a folder from their machine and then play music through my site. Is this possible? If so, how should I implement it. I have seen a couple different players that look alright but I am not to sure how to get the player on my site. I am very new to HTML5, Javascript and CSS. I also saw the audio tags which is built with html5 but i dont know if that is the best way to go.

Comment: http://danml.com/wizamp/